# How can I make my input for my neural net include both vectorized text and a one-hot encoding?

Tags: keras, tensorflow, lstm, one-hot-encoding

Suppose I'm trying to classify fake news on dataset like [this one,](https://www.kaggle.com/clmentbisaillon/fake-and-real-news-dataset) where there are columns that show the text of an article as well as a tag for the article that can help classify it. I could vectorize the article text and use an LSTM to train a fake news predicter on it, which would require an input layer of something like this

```
import tensorflow    
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras import Input

model = Sequential()
model.add(Input(shape=(1,), dtype=tensorflow.string))
```

Then, I'd add a text-vectorization layer, then the LSTM, so on and so forth. However, what if I wanted to one-hot encode the `subject` column in the dataset, as that could be a column that could help the model during training? And what if I wanted to also include the article title? I'd ideally want to have my x-data be of the form `[[vectorized text for the article],[vectorized text for the title],[one-hot encoding of the news subject]]`.

Clearly, the input layer I have above wouldn't be robust enough to handle input like that. How would I be able to feed this as an input to my neural net?

Answer (score 1):

One option is to manually tokenize the text using a [TextVectorization](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/TextVectorization)

layer before the model, and simply concatenate your desired components together to form one long vector of integers.

Comment: Would I vectorize the text before or after concatenating all the text together? Wouldn't that be a disingenuous representation of the text? It's as if I decided to put the article title and subject in place before the text synthetically, when it was never there to begin with.

Comment: I can't speak to the specifics of the implementation as I have not done it before, however what you can do is something like this:
say you have n elements in a vector representing the text embedding of the article, m elements in a vector representing the text embedding of the title, and x elements in a vector representing any other feature you desire. As long as these integers are fixed, and always concatenated in the same order, the model will be trained to treat them as their own features, and will work just as any other model. There would be no issues, since each feature is independent

Comment: Just keep in mind that one-hot encoding takes the size of your vocabulary for the title & again for the subject making the concatenated vectors huge. This will diminish learning due to the curse of dimensionality requiring orders of magnitude more examples to compensate for. Perhaps you want to consider other denser representations like word/doc2vec or bundle several parts into the same encoding scheme & space.